# Using the COUNTIF function in Excel to tally how many times a string of words appear in a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, countif

This is probably very simple but I can't figure it out after searching all around the web.

I have two worksheets in play. One called "Pieces" which lists names of magazine short stories which have been written. Each piece is only listed once.

The second sheet called "Submission Record" details the place and the date the pieces were sent to. The names of the pieces appear several times.

On "Pieces" worksheet I want to have a cell tell me how often each piece was submitted. This data is found in "Submission Record"

Here's the formula I have:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT ('Submission Record'!B1:B200,"Name of the story")
```

It doesn't work. How can I change it?

I also tried this:

```
=COUNTIF('Submission Record! B1:B200',"Name of the story")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this modification on the formula syntax:

```
=COUNTIF('Submission Record'!B1:B200,"Name of the story")
```

Comment: Also note that the formula is looking for exact matches.  If you have other spaces or characters it wont count it.